# Select query to fetch 5 5 rows based on different column values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mysql-workbench, multiple-select-query

I have an Invoice table which contains invoice data in each row where an invoice can be in different state such as due, overdue, disputed and partially paid. Below is the table structure:

| Invoice_no | due_state | disputed_state | paid_state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| inv1 | due | dispute_none | paid_none |
| inv2 | overdue | disputed | partially_paid |
| inv3 | due | disputed | partially_paid |

I need to fetch 5 invoices which are in due state, 5 invoices which are in overdue state, 5 invoices which are in disputed state and 5 invoices which are in partially paid state in single mysql query.

Currently I'm running 5 different sqls to fetch results for each states.
Please help me to create one sql to fetch invoices for each states in a single sql query.

I'm using mysql database. Currently I'm doing it as

```
Select * from table where due_state = 'due' limit 5;

Select * from table where due_state = 'overdue' limit 5;

Select * from table where diputed_state = 'disputed' limit 5;

Select * from table where paid_state = 'partially_paid' limit 5
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply:

- `UNION ALL` if you want 20 records with potential duplicates
- `UNION` if you are allowing less than 20 unique records, among which there can be records that satisfy more conditions at the same time.

```
Select * from table where due_state = 'due' limit 5
UNION [ALL]
Select * from table where due_state = 'overdue' limit 5
UNION [ALL]
Select * from table where diputed_state = 'disputed' limit 5
UNION [ALL]
Select * from table where paid_state = 'partially_paid' limit 5
```

Note: `[ALL]` is the optional keyword to be added without brackets or removed completely from the final query.

Comment: Thanks I'll check this but is there any other way around. What if I have to join another table with this table? That will make the sql longer....

Comment: Do you have overlapping records?